# Visual Studio 2010 C++ awkward linker erratic behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, compilation

Working on a big project I have bumped into this problem: from time to time the linker refuses to "see" the implementation of a class, throwing "symbol not found" exceptions wherever methods of that particular class (Board) are found.

Some 'technical' details:

- I use #pragma once on my .cpp files. I know that in the end they don't do (or shouldn't do) anything since .cpp files are not included in others, but I developed this bad habit of writing that at the top of every code file I create.
- The class implements ALL of the methods declared in its .h file
- The class includes other headers of the project, but the same headers are included in many files, yet this particular class is the ONLY one which has compilation problems.
- The problems began to appear shortly after I wrote a template class which my class includes and uses, but, as mentioned above, other classes have no problem with it (so I can't tell whether the template is or not truly related to the problem).

and the weirdest part is:

- When the linker fails with the "symbol not found" exception (it does this only SOME of the times), if I toggle the #pragma once directive in the class .cpp file, the next compilation works. This means that sometime I need to comment "#pragma once" in order to get a successful compilation, other times I need to uncomment it.

If you need any more information, like the .h and .cpp files of the class, I will write it asap.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

Some more info:

- When the problem first appeared, I tried to comment as many methods and fields of the class as possible, trying to isolate the problem. On an occasion, removing the link between the class and the template resulted in a good compile, but later on it didn't really matter. Adding instances of the class in different parts of my project (files/namespaces/etc) didn't make any difference either.
- Visual Studio is installed on C:\, the project is on D:\, both partitions are NTFS.
- This is the only project I have problems with, I have made and compiled and ran successfully many other projects before and after the problem began on this one with the same programming style.
- I tried rebuilding the whole project and cleaning up .obj files by hand when the problem appears and it did not make any difference.

Comment: Do you have the implementation of the template code in the .cpp ?

Comment: No, I have it in a .h file, since, as far as I know, you can't separate the declaration and the implementation of a template in different files. I write templates pretty much as C# classes are written.

Comment: @cantrem: Okay, good. :) Next, do you **only** need to change that `#pragma once` if the linking fails or do you change anything else? What about a direct recompile without any change?

Comment: ONLY that and it works. I'm not sure what you mean by "direct recompile". If you're talking about rebuilding all the project than no, I tried it a couple of times and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @cantrem: Yes, that's what I meant, just a direct rebuild after it fails. What happens if you change any other line and try to recompile?

Comment: Didn't try that yet. I'm thinking (if I can't come up with a better solution) of finding another machine with vs2010 installed to move my project to and see what happens then.

Comment: I edited my comment to reserve the reinstallation as the last option. :)

Comment: @Xeo: well, that's another fun part: when the problem first appeared, I tried to comment as many methods and fields of the class as possible, trying to isolate the problem. On an occasion, removing the link between the class and the template resulted in a good compile, but later on it didn't really matter. Adding instances of the class in different parts of my project (files/namespaces/etc) didn't make any difference either.

Comment: @cantrem: Okay, then what *exactly* is the linker error message? Maybe edit it in the question.

Comment: When the problem is reproducing, how large is the relevant obj file and what does link /verbose say?

Have you tried disabling your virus scanner (before the problem happens)? Is the file on a filesystem other than NTFS (e.g. FAT, network)?

Comment: @Xeo: when I'll bump again in the problem (it's gone for now), I'll copy-paste it. It basically is the good old "symbol not found" exception and it appears every time a method of the class is called. This includes the constructors of the class. It complains about not finding implementations for any of the class's methods.

Comment: @Martyn: NTFS. visual studio is on the windows partition, the project on another, they are both NTFS. About the size of the .obj I have no idea. Should I be looking for a size change between good and unsuccessful compilations? Also I did not check link /verbose and my antivirus has always been on, but it doesn't show any messages when I compile. I had an antivirus problem once with a C# project, but then all its lights went up and the final .exe file went in quarantine (although it was a different antivirus).

Comment: I would check the date and size of the obj next time. My suspicion is that the file is either empty or out of date and not getting rebuilt right.

Bad AV software can screw up file-writes even when it doesn't find viruses. I generally disable it for the drive where build outputs and temporaries go.

Answer (score 0):

This link http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7877/ provides interesting discussion for the different styles of incude guards.
That suggests cases when #pragma once fails , may be that can help you.

My feeing is to avoid #pragma once, for portable code.

Comment: I don't think that link covers my case. True, pragmas are not portable, but since I only work (at least for now) on a Windows machine using the VS2010 compiler, it shouldn't be a problem. Also, the problem is still there even if I remove the pragma directive from the class' implementation file. And I really hope that other pragmas from some other files aren't the cause of my problem.

Comment: `#pragma once` is useless in a .cpp (or translation unit, if you want the official name). It is only useful for headers, as such should not matter anyways.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the reasons I find this bug (if it truly is a bug) very strange.